# OperationalError at /admin/rentals/rental/

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-admin, django-1.9

I had a database with following fields **listingName,slug,property,city,place,ownerName,room,water,amenities,price,summary,phoneNumber,phone_image,email**
I didn't want phone_image field so i removed it from models.py and applied the following command

```
python manage.py makemigrations rentals
python manage.py migrate
```

But i get below error

```
OperationalError at /admin/rentals/rental/
no such column: rentals_rental.phone_image
```

so i deleted my database first and then applied the command python manage.py migrate but still getting the same error though my models do not have phone_image field.

It works in localhost but not in remote. As i have hosted my application in digital ocean with nginx and gunicorn.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rentals.models import Rental,Gallery

class InlineGallery(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Gallery
    fk_name = 'rental'

class RentalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        InlineGallery,
    ]
admin.site.register(Rental,RentalAdmin)
admin.site.register(Gallery)
```

**models.py**

```
ownerName = models.CharField(_("Owner's Name"),max_length=255, blank=True,null=True,
    help_text=_("Owner's Full Name"))
email = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)
phoneNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
    help_text=_("Phone number of contact person"))
listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
    help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,null=True,help_text=_("Description of the rental space"))
property = models.CharField(_("Property type"),max_length=10,null=True)
room = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("No of Rooms"), blank=False, null=True,
    help_text=_("Number of bedrooms available"))
price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
    help_text=_("Rental price of the space per month"))
city =  models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
    help_text=_("City of the rental space"))
place =  models.CharField(_("Place"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
    help_text=_("Place of the rental space"))
water = models.CharField(_("water facilities"),max_length=50,null=True,
    help_text=_("Is there water facility?"))
amenities = models.CharField(_("amenities"),max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
phone_image = models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='image form of the phone number', max_length=2048, null=True)
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.listingName
```

I have two migrations file inside migration folder

**0001_initial.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.1 on 2016-03-30 14:23
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Gallery',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('image', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='upload/')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Galleries',
            'verbose_name': 'Gallery',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Rental',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('ownerName', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text="Owner's Full Name", max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name="Owner's Name")),
            ('email', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=120, null=True)),
            ('phoneNumber', models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text='Phone number of contact person', null=True)),
            ('listingName', models.CharField(help_text='Title of the rental space', max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name='Lisitng Name')),
            ('slug', models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)),
            ('summary', models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Description of the rental space', max_length=500, null=True)),
            ('property', models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, verbose_name='Property type')),
            ('room', models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text='Number of bedrooms available', null=True, verbose_name='No of Rooms')),
            ('price', models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text='Rental price of the space per month', null=True)),
            ('city', models.CharField(help_text='City of the rental space', max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name='City')),
            ('place', models.CharField(help_text='Place of the rental space', max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name='Place')),
            ('water', models.CharField(help_text='Is there water facility?', max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='water facilities')),
            ('amenities', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='amenities')),
            ('phone_image', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='image form of the phone number', max_length=2048, null=True)),
            ('is_published', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ('created_on', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ('modified_on', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Rents',
            'verbose_name': 'Rent',
        },
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='gallery',
        name='rental',
        field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='gallery', to='rentals.Rental', verbose_name='Rental'),
    ),
]
```

**0002_remove_rental_phone_image.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.1 on 2016-04-20 02:01
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('rentals', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='rental',
        name='phone_image',
    ),
]
```

How can i overcome this issue? Do i need to provide any more information?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that in the first migration it sais `model_name='Rental'` but in the second it sais `model_name='rental'`(lower case). did you rename your model by any chance?

Comment: No i have not changed the model name. It is Rental.

Comment: Please post your `admin.py`

Comment: Check your database if the field `phone_image` is available in the table `rental` if not, it got removed somehow.

Comment: @TimSchneider The OP intentionally removed it from the model.

Comment: I updated my question with admin.py

Comment: Ok, maybe I interpreted the question wrong. It might not be a problem of the migrations after all. Did the `manage.py migrate` command work without problems?

Comment: Did you restart your django instance after the migration?

Comment: Yes. it did not work so i added phone_image fields back in models.py and it worked. I will update my models.py and migrations files. Please let me know what steps i apply to remove phone_image field without any error.

Comment: you said that it works on localhost but on remote machine it doesn't work right? Did you removed migration files from that remote machine?

Comment: when it did not work i removed it. But now i have copied to previous state.

Comment: its working now with phone_image field after i have revert back to previous state of my models which i have updated in my question. Now i want to remove phone_image field. So can i remove phone_image field from the models and then apply makemigrations rentals and migrate command respectively ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the answers above, the field got manually removed from the database, so the migration tries to delete a field that is no longer existing in the database.

Normally you should never delete fields directly in the db but use the migrations instead. As the field is already gone you can now only fake the migration to tell django that the changes were already made:

```
manage.py migrate rentals 0002 --fake
```

Make sure though that you are at migration 0001, otherwise that would be faked aswell.

just to be sure, you could run the following command first:

```
manage.py migrate rentals 0001
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error means that, there is no any column named `phone_image` in the table `rental`. So, your second migration is trying to remove a column that is not present in the table `rental`. Somehow, you removed that column from the table, and django migration system didn't notice it.

As a fix try one of these options:

**1)** delete `0002_remove_rental_phone_image.py` and in `0001_initial.py` remove this line: 
`('phone_image', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='image form of the phone number'....))`, 
and try to apply migrations (if it says: `table rental is already exist`, try to `DROP` it from the database);

**2)** delete all your migration files, and recreate the database, make migrations and apply them.

Comment: This could lead to data loss which could be a problem.

Comment: yes, but @pri says: `deleted my database first` that's why I have proposed this option.

Comment: I deleted my migration files and also db.sqlite3 and applied python manage.py migrate but did not work either

Comment: Like @TimSchneider said, it could lead to data loss but this is my first attempt and there is no any data yet. However it might be critical issue once i have data in my database which i dont want to loose.

Comment: I have already tried both options you stated but none of these worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you write your code of models.py
then Run Command

```
python manage.py makemigrations rentals
```

after this command you will see 0001_any_name.py then Enter again command

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate rentals 0001    //0001 is prefix of above result
```

It will create your database accouding to models.py then you can migrate

```
python manage.pt migrate
```

So this process run first time when you first time create database but in any database column problem occurs then this above procedure repeat again.your problem will solve.